# How to correctly translate a library monorepo with react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am creating a monorepo, with NX, containing only libraries to be used by other projects. I would like to localize/translate them using *i18next*.
The thing is, there's no entry point in these libraries, just random react components to be exported that require some internal translations.

**Should I export the i18next instance so the user of the library is the one that needs to wrap their application with a I18NextProvider**, or should each component get wrapped in the I18NextProvider (which doesn't sound right and a bit overkill)?

Comment: So, any solution to this? I am starting a project right now, and I'm right in the same spot you were - how to provide i18n to component libraries.

Comment: I still haven't found any solution, unfortunatelly

Comment: I ended up going with LinguiJS - even though it's a smaller (in terms of downloads per week) lib, I was able to make it work well within my monorepo. I'm currently working on a step-by-step about how to do it, as Lingui's docs currently are not very clear about that, if you're interested I'll update this comment later, or maybe answer the question with it.

Comment: Great, will check it out for sure. Please do, I would love that, thanks for that